# Having a hard time with a blank space between divs

Tags: css

A client of mine asked me to take his code and make it responsive; He used to display his news in 2 column divs (left-side / right-side) and for responsiveness sake's I had to get rid of those 2 columns and put all of the news next to each others, but I'm getting a blank space between rows (2nd news width's is pushing 3rd new away)

This is what the html looks like

```
<main>
<article class="news">blabla</article>
<article class="news">blabla</article>
<article class="news">blabla</article>
<article class="news">blabla</article>
</main>
```

And this is the css

```
.news {
width: 335px;
background: #F0EEFF;
display: inline-block;
padding:.3em 0;
padding-left: 0.3em;
vertical-align: top;
```

}

[image: See it for yourself]

```css
.noticia {
 width: 335px;
 background: #F0EEFF;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:.3em 0;
 padding-left: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: top;
}


.noticia>img, .noticia .video, .noticia iframe {
 width: 335px;
 max-width: 99%;
}
```

```html
  <main> <!-- modulo de notas -->
   <article class="noticia">
    <h6 class="categoria">Internacional</h6>
    <h2>El ministro de economía español visitará este miércoles el pais</h2>
    <img src="images/noticia4.png">
    <div class="bajada">bajada bajada bajada bajadabajada bajadabajada bajada</div>
    <div class="texto-noticia"><p>Será luego de 5 años de ausencia, se reunirá con otros ministros en la casa Rosada</p></div>
    <div> 
    <img src="images/AUDIO.png">
    </div>
    <div class="comentarios">Dejar un comentario - Leer más...<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/face.png"></a>   <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></div>
    <hr>
   </article>
   <article class="noticia">
    <h6 class="categoria">Internacional</h6>
    <h2>El ministro de economía español visitará este miércoles el pais</h2>
    <img src="images/noticia4.png">
    <div class="texto-noticia"><p>Será luego de 5 años de ausencia, se Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.reunirá con otros ministros en la casa Rosada</p></div>
    <div class="comentarios">Dejar un comentario - Leer más...<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/face.png"></a>   <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></div>
    <hr>
    <aside class="banner">
    <img src="images/banner1.png"></img>
    </aside>
   </article>
   <article class="noticia">
    <h6 class="categoria">Internacional</h6>
    <h2>El ministro de economía español visitará este miércoles el pais</h2>
    <img src="images/noticia4.png">
    <div class="texto-noticia"><p>Será luego de 5 años de ausencia, se reunirá con otros ministros en la casa Rosada</p></div>
    <div class="comentarios">Dejar un comentario - Leer más...<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/face.png"></a>   <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></div>
    <hr>
    <aside class="banner">
     <object width="100%" height="104.53125">
             <param name="src" value="http://www.supropiositio.com/04-2015/3df40c4be1bd964ca95f9250b5a5f504.swf">
             <embed src="http://www.supropiositio.com/04-2015/3df40c4be1bd964ca95f9250b5a5f504.swf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/" width="100%" height="104.53125">
          </object>
    </aside>
   </article>
   <article class="noticia">
    <h6 class="categoria">Internacional</h6>
    <h2>El ministro de economía español visitará este miércoles el pais</h2>
    <img src="images/noticia4.png">
    <div class="video"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qGsTlYLbwy4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div>
    <div class="texto-noticia"><p>Será luego de 5 años de ausencia, se reunirá con otros ministros en la casa Rosada</p></div>
    <div class="comentarios">Dejar un comentario - Leer más...<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/face.png"></a>   <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></div>
    <hr>
    <aside class="banner">
    <img src="images/banner1.png"></img>
    </aside>
   </article>
  </main>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to have a working snippet of your difficulty. That would be helpful for helping you!

Comment: Yup, sorry Jon, here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ajoyymoL/

Comment: Would you consider using `float:left;` on `.noticia`?

Comment: It was my initial idea but it didn't change a thing, it looked pretty much the same, white spaces where still there

Comment: you could still use column css setting only width, it would break in as many column space allow 1 to x columns. https://jsfiddle.net/ajoyymoL/1/ else you may use mediaqueries or sort this out with javascritpt ( like http://masonry.desandro.com/ )

Comment: @GerardoSabetta Keep in mind that you may need at least `IE 10` while using `column-count`

Comment: @trix if news remain inline-block, you have the fallback already here, with the gap of couse

Comment: Trix I tried to remove the spaces from the code, putting comments in between and it didn't solve it I'll use column-count for the moment, thanks!

Comment: @GCyrillus thats not a fallback, because the gaps make at least the last item go the next line. @ Gerardo Sabetta It works, u may have missed something

Comment: @Trix well, witout inline-block, they stack on each othe(one each row)r, if it had no gap, then it would be an alternative ... and there would be no questions :)  we might have a different understanding of a fallback. my english isn't that good anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal way divs works. The next div start where the last end. In your case, the 3rd div will start always at the bottom of the second div, so its position depends on the length of the last div.

The most aproximate solution with only CSS is the CSS3 columns properties:

```
main {
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-width: 335px;
   -moz-column-width: 335px;
   column-width: 335px;
}
.noticia {
    background: #F0EEFF;
    padding:.3em 0;
}
```

But this will order the elements top-to-bottom, and not left-to-right like the user usually expect.

So, if the items order has to be left-to-right you need to use a javascript solution like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: It is not the best, as it needs at least `IE10`

Comment: He did not mention any browser requirement, plus IE < 11 versions are currently deprecated, we shouldn't continue giving support for these versions if even Microsoft didn't do it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: copy of comment up there : " if news remain inline-block, you have the fallback already here, with the gap of couse"

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the display: inline-block any more, of course, you can remove that. I have edited my answer with all the code

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't solve the problem as it nows displays the recents news in the left column and the oldest in the right; It's the same as using divs "left-side"/"right-side"

Comment: I think your problem was the blank space between rows. How is the layout you are looking for? Is not two columns? I think I am missing something...

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. You will need to use masonry.js or other javascript solution, it is not possible with CSS

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to remove that white space gap, when using `display: inline-block`:

```
<main>
    <article class="news">blabla</article><article class="news">blabla</article><article class="news">blabla</article>
</main>

<main>
    <article class="news">blabla</article><article class="news">
    blabla</article><article class="news">
    blabla</article>
</main>

<main>
    <article class="news">blabla</article
    ><article class="news">blabla</article
    ><article class="news">blabla</article>
</main>

<main>
    <article class="news">blabla</article><!--
    --><article class="news">blabla</article><!--
    --><article class="news">blabla</article>
</main>
```

Comment: it is not that gap wich is involved here (float would leave the same) , problem is that boxes of different heights are going row by row. did see the red arrow on the screenshot ?